# how to invoke multiple http webservice in mule flow in transaction?

Tags: spring, hibernate, mule, mule-studio

I am new to mule.
I have a spring-hibernate mule setup. Suppose there are 3 webservice.Aim is to invoke all those webservice in a mule flow so that all 3 will be in a transaction. so that suppose if 3rd webservice fails then the previous 2 will be rolled back automatically.

Here is my code snippet what I tried.
my mule-flow.xml(`currently I have only one webservice,kindly let me know how can I add multipe webservice call in flow?`)

```
<spring:beans>
 <spring:import resource="classpath:spring-mule.xml"/>
 <spring:import resource="classpath:applicationContext-persistence.xml"/>
</spring:beans>

<flow name="addCustomer" doc:name="addCustomer">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
address="http://localhost:8081/pos/addCustomer" doc:name="HTTP" />

<cxf:simple-service serviceClass="com.proj.pos.webservice.interfac.CustomerService" doc:name="SOAP"/>
<component ><spring-object bean="customerService"/></component>
</flow>

</mule>
```

My spring-mule.xml

```
<bean id="customerService"  class="com.proj.pos.webservice.implementation.CustomerServiceImpl">
    <property name="cusDao" >
    <ref local="customerDao"/>
    </property>
    </bean>
```

My:applicationContext-persistence.xml

```
     <bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
<property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" />
<property name="username" value="xyz" />
<property name="password" value="xyz" />
</bean> 

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

     <bean id="customerDao" class="com.proj.pos.dao.implementation.CustomerDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
    <ref local="sessionFactory"/>
    </property>
    </bean>
```

my CustomerServiceImpl

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.proj.pos.webservice.interfac.CustomerService",
        serviceName = "CustomerService")
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerDao cusDao;

    @Transactional  //NOTE:USING THIS ANNOTATION I AM ABLE TO ACHIEVE THE BELOW METHOD //IN TRANSACTION,BUT I BELEIVE THIS FEATURE WILL NOT WORK IF WE HAVE MULTIPLE WEBSERVICE CALL
    @Override
    public Customer addCustomer(CustomerDto dto) {
        Customer customer=new Customer(dto.getCustomerId(), dto.getFname(), dto.getLname(), dto.getAge(), dto.getDateOfBirth(), dto.getAddress());
        customer.setCustomerId(cusDao.persist(customer));
         return customer;
    }

    public CustomerDao getCusDao() {
        return cusDao;
    }

    public void setCusDao(CustomerDao cusDao) {
        this.cusDao = cusDao;
    }

}
```

Please let me know any solution.Thanks

Comment: are you trying to expose or consume multiple webservices?

Comment: I am trying to expose webservice..the above code is not a code for webservice client so I believe,I am trying to expose webservice..

Comment: and what would the condition to invoke one web service or another would be?

Comment: no condition..I would like to queue the call using mule flow

Comment: What protocol are you using for your service ? Have you considered WS-AtomicTransaction (WS-AT) (SOAP) ?

Comment: I am using SOAP protocol

Comment: OASIS has defined several standards to achieve this. for example : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Atomic_Transaction

Answer (score 1):

By seeing your question what I understood is your trying to make 3 web-service calls and you want to make all three calls in a single transaction.

As you are making a call to another system (Web-service in your case) you don't have control to maintain the transaction.

In your case you can use a Scatter gather router to call three web-services if any route(web-service call) is failed it will throw `CompositeRoutingException`, you can very well catch this exception in your catch exception strategy.

In your catch exception strategy you need to do the roll back activities (make another web-service call or db call which will fulfill your rollback requirement ).

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you have a three or more webservices calls and some db operations. you want to rollback if any service call fails.

Write a spring bean as below for SpringTransactionFactory and set transationManager property (ref from your applicationContext-persistence.xml)

```
<spring:beans>
 <spring:import resource="classpath:spring-mule.xml"/>
 <spring:import resource="classpath:applicationContext-persistence.xml"/>
 <spring:bean id = "transactionFactory" class = "org.mule.module.spring.transaction.SpringTransactionFactory">
    <spring:property ref="transactionManager" name=""></spring:property>
 </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
```

And add a tansactionfactory ref to inboundEndpoint as below

```
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
                address="http://localhost:8081/pos/addCustomer" doc:name="HTTP" >
                <custom-transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" factory-ref="transactionFactory"/>
                </http:inbound-endpoint>
```

Complete flow will be in single transaction and inclouding dao classes